# jqgrid in dialog - search operator dropdown list doesn't work

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

please check here
 **jsfiddle.net/zdACB/4/**

Why dropdown list with search operations doesn't work. When I don't use dialog everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

See, I have done only from thingy column. Here http://jsfiddle.net/symonsarwar/zdACB/6/ there should be

```
stype:'select'
```

in the column model
Only changed the column model

```
 {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date",
        stype:'select',
        searchoptions:{
            value:"1:sss;2:eee;3:fff;4:ccc",sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}
    },
```